# Matrix N x N x 3, get the first element of the inner 3 array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy matrix which represents an image and I want to effectively get an array of the first element of every color. The matrix is of size N x M x 3, and x 3 because they are colors. What I want is to sum all the for example the reds. An example next:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(2,4,3))
 a
array([[[1, 8, 8],[9, 9, 9],[4, 7, 7],[7, 1, 5]],[[3, 2, 2],[8, 5, 4],[3, 3, 5],[2, 2, 7]]])
sum_r = 0
for i in a:
    for j in i:
         sum_r += j[0]
print(sum_r)
37
1 + 9 + 4 + 7 + 3 + 8 + 3 + 2
37
```

Comment: I need to do that in a effective way because the N and M are very big

Comment: `a[:,:,0].sum()`, or `a.sum(axis=(0,1))`

Comment: I love you, really thx, my genetic algorithm was super slow, saved my booty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sumColumn(m):
    return [sum(col) for col in zip(*m)]


column = 0
matrix = [[1 , 4, 5, 12], 
          [-5, 8, 9, 0],
          [-6, 7, 11, 19]]

print("Sum of the elements in column", sumColumn(matrix)[column])
```

Comment: Thx, but I was rather looking for a fast efficient solution like a[:,0] or something like that